# Sort lists of dictionaries within dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

**EDIT:**
I'm editing the whole post as it wasn't as clear as I thougt.

I have this dictionary (list of dictionaries within a dictionary) and I need to sort it by the values of `"Position"` and `"Team"`, meaning that I need to get all the values from those two keys and print them as I show below. I know how to get each value, but I don't know how to get them and sort them.

```
dic = {"Racing" : [ {"Team" : "Racing",
                     "Player" : "Player 1",
                     "Position" : "GK" },
                    {"Team" : "Racing",
                     "Player" : "Player 2",
                     "Position" : "DF"} ],
       "Independiente" : [ {"Team" : "Independiente",
                            "Player" : "Player A",
                            "Position" : "GK"},
                           {"Team" : "Independiente",
                            "Player" : "Player B",
                            "Position" : "DF"} ]
       }
```

I tried this piece of code, but I still can't get it to work.

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1][2], item[1][0]))}
```

My actual dictionary is much bigger than this one, and I pretend to make it even bigger. I need the output to be something like:

```
DF - Independiente
DF - Racing
GK - Independiente
GK - Racing
```

In this example I only included strings, but I need to also sort similar dictionaries by integer values.

Comment: I'm sure somebody will give you a good answer, take a look at doing some recursion. :)

Comment: When you say by position and team, do you want lexicographic sorting of position?

Comment: I will edit to clarify my question.

Comment: Please show your desired result, too.

Comment: Also, please show your code attempt that isn't working.

Comment: it's not clear what you want. Do you want it to be sorted inside the `dic` itself or you want a new list of dictionary. You are trying to create a dictionary with multiple same keys which is not possible.

Comment: Liked " It's not clear what you want."

Comment: I thought it was clear. I need to print the sorted dictionary by value. I'm not creating a dictionary with multiple same keys. Each inner dictionary share the same keys. I don't know how to get the values from the inner dictionary so as to sort it and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract values of dic as tuple of `(Position, Team)`,
Concatenate them to create flattened tuple of `(Position, Team)` elements.
Sort them with sorted

```
dic = {"Racing" : [ {"Team" : "Racing",
                     "Player" : "Player 1",
                     "Position" : "GK" },
                    {"Team" : "Racing",
                     "Player" : "Player 2",
                     "Position" : "DF"} ],
       "Independiente" : [ {"Team" : "Independiente",
                            "Player" : "Player A",
                            "Position" : "GK"},
                           {"Team" : "Independiente",
                            "Player" : "Player B",
                            "Position" : "DF"} ]
       }

res = ()
#           emit as tuple of (Position, Team) from all of dic's values
for PT in ( tuple((team['Position'], team['Team']) for team in v) for v in dic.values() ):
    res = res + PT
    # concatenate all tuples to flatten into one large tuple
res = sorted(res)
# sort tuple of (Position, Team) values

print(res)

# create string representation in format "Position - Team\n..."
print("\n".join(" - ".join(r) for r in res))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It seems that my post wasn't as unclear as others said! I actually simplified my question for the sake of brevity and simplicity, but in my program I am using two comboboxes to select the fields of a CSV file to sort the output in a textbox. So, when running the app I don't really know the sorting fields. They are retrieved from a CSV file, and I built the program to get almost any CSV file. This code works perfectly! I only tweaked it to get the sorting fields from the combos. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A solution i found is use an auxiliar dict, in which you save the teams in positions. And then sort by team and position in when you output data. E.g:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = {"Racing" : [ {"Team" : "Racing",
                     "Player" : "Player 1",
                     "Position" : "GK" },
                    {"Team" : "Racing",
                     "Player" : "Player 2",
                     "Position" : "DF"} ],
       "Independiente" : [ {"Team" : "Independiente",
                            "Player" : "Player A",
                            "Position" : "GK"},
                           {"Team" : "Independiente",
                            "Player" : "Player B",
                            "Position" : "DF"} ]
       }
       
dict = defaultdict(list)
for team in dic:
    for player in dic[team]:
        dict[player["Position"]].append(player["Team"])
for position in sorted(dict.keys()):
    for item in sorted(dict[position]):
        print(f"{position} - {item}")
```

output:

```
DF - Independiente
DF - Racing
GK - Independiente
GK - Racing
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'sort by position and team' and write what you wrote for an output.

If you want your output to be...

```
DF - Independiente
DF - Racing
GK - Independiente
GK - Racing
```

Then you want this, stored however you want to store it. In a list or new dict maybe.

```
for i in dic.values():
    print(list(i[1].values())[2]+' - '+list(i[1].values())[0])
    print(list(i[1].values())[2]+' - '+list(i[0].values())[0])
```